# Elevar permisos de ejecución de script - PHP

Tags: php

Un Saludo,

Tengo el siguiente Script:

```
$mon = exec( 'tail -n 10 /var/log/maillog');
echo $mon;
```

Pero el log que deseo monitorear tiene privilegios para ser abierto como root y al ejecutar mi script no muestra nada.

Se que con un comando desde la terminal de linux `# chmod 777 maillog` pudiera resolver el problema, pero me gustaría saber si desde el Script de php puedo elevar los permisos que tiene mi script a root para ejecutar archivos que requieren dicha permisología.

Se que desde Perl podía hacer algo parecido con `nice -n -3`pero no se si exista en php una función que me permita hacer lo que quiero.

Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

No vas a poder  auto elevar lo privilegios del script. y de ser posible seria un problema de seguridad. Lo que puedes hacer es si solo quieres leer. añadir permisos 644 o 774. dependiendo lo que necesites pero dejando el ultimo numero en 4 para darle a "otros" solo permiso de lectura. O agregar al grupo del usuario que creo la carpeta "maillog" el usuario que ejecuta php.